# How do I create a request in Swagger Inspector that accepts multiple data types?

Tags: multipartform-data, swagger-inspector

I am currently trying to submit a request using the Swagger Inspector using multipart/form-data header to allow the submission of a file in conjunction with json data.

The JSON body of my request looks like:

[image: Json Body]

And the headers with file upload look like:

[image: Headers]

For requests where I am just sending json to the server the Content-Type header is set to application/json and it is able to read from the body box. However I do not understand how this interface allows me to specify that the information coming from the body field is json and despite there being files on on the request.

I have seen requests that define multiple data types using the Conetent-Disspostion header, that look this this (reffenced from this [Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean/28380690#answer-28380690)):

```
    POST / HTTP/1.1
[[ Less interesting headers ... ]]
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Length: 834

-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text1"

text default
-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text2"

aωb
-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Content of a.txt.

-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="a.html"
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html><title>Content of a.html.</title>

-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file3"; filename="binary"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

aωb
-----------------------------735323031399963166993862150--
```

My question would be how do I create a request in swagger inspector that accepts multiple data types? It seems like I would need to set mulple sections in the body separated by boundaries with multiple Content-Disposition and Content-Type's for each. Would there be a cleaner way to do that through the Swagger Inspector interface? Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger Inspector currently supports `multipart/form-data` requests containing one or more *files*. It does not support arbitrary body parts in multipart requests (e.g. a file + JSON or text data). You'll need to use another HTTP client to test such requests.

You can submit feature request for Swagger Inspector here:
https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Inspector-Feature/idb-p/SwaggerInspectorFeatureRequests